# Magento - Get wishlist share link from template

Tags: magento

Is it possible to get the wishlist share link (usually generated via an email when shared with a friend) before the email, IE from the template directly? I want to share this via Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by the following code in `.../template/wishlist/view.phtml`

```
Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $this->getWishlistInstance()->getSharingCode()))
```

Comment: were you able to share the wishlist? as when i paste the sharer link in another browser it shows wishlist is empty

Comment: wishlist share link not working showing 404 error??   when add to cart  but work when open wishlist item